# Is a Bose 802C incompatible with a Soundcraft Ui16?

Tags: pa

I have an old Soundcraft RacPac mixer connected to a Bose 802C controller then to an amp and speakers. It works fine. When I connect a new Soundcraft Ui16 to the Bose 802C in place of the RacPac I get only a loud mains hum. Same thing with XLR or TRS leads. Connecting the Ui16 direct to the amp, bypassing the Bose controller, eliminates the hum. Is the Bose 802C incompatible with the Ui16? Jon, Sheffield

Comment: A diagram on the cover of Bose 802C shows standard XLR pin layout, nothing obviously incompatible. A common cause of mains hum is a ground loop. Have you tried using the same power strip for all devices? You could also try putting a DI box with ground lift between Soundcraft and Bose...

Comment: Many thanks for your advice. The diagram on the 802C shows pin 3 hot, which is unusual. The rest of the system is pin 2 hot but the system works fine with the old RacPac mixer so the pins seem ok We have a power strip with one earth connection. When I use the RacPac there's no hum. We've tried a passive DI box between the  mixer and the 802C. Same result - no hum with the old RacPac and lots of hum with the Ui16. When used with a Bose L1 stick system the Ui16 works fine. It also works fine with our old amps and 802 speakers when I bypass the 802C controller.